# How to use newBackgroundContext() with URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, combine, ios-multithreading

I have created [a simple Core Data project at Github](https://github.com/afarber/ios-questions/tree/master/Tops1) to demonstrate my problem:

[image: Xcode screenshot]

My test app downloads a JSON list of objects, stores it in Core Data and displays in a SwiftUI List via `@FetchRequest`.

Because the list of objects has 1000+ elements in my *real* app, I would like to save the entities into the Core Data on a background thread and not on the main thread.

Preferably I would like to use the same default background thread, which is already used by the [URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/datataskpublisher).

So in the standard [Persistence.swift](https://github.com/afarber/ios-questions/blob/master/Tops1/Tops1/Persistence.swift) generated by Xcode I have added only 2 lines:

```
container.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergePolicy.mergeByPropertyObjectTrump
container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
```

and in my [DownloadManager.swift](https://github.com/afarber/ios-questions/blob/master/Tops1/Tops1/Managers/DownloadManager.swift) singleton I call:

```
static let instance = DownloadManager()

var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

// How to run this line on the background thread of URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher?
let backgroundContext = PersistenceController.shared.container.newBackgroundContext()

private init() {
    getTops()
}

func getTops() {
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://slova.de/ws/top") else { return }
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
        .tryMap(handleOutput)
        .decode(type: TopResponse.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
        .sink { completion in
            print(completion)
        } receiveValue: { [weak self] returnedTops in
            for top in returnedTops.data {
                // the next line fails with EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION
                let topEntity = TopEntity(context: self!.backgroundContext)
                topEntity.uid = Int32(top.id)
                topEntity.elo = Int32(top.elo)
                topEntity.given = top.given
                topEntity.avg_score = top.avg_score ?? 0.0
            }
            self?.save()
        }
        .store(in: &cancellables)
}
```

As you can see in the above screenshot, this fails with

> Thread 4: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

because I have added the following "Arguments Passed on Launch" in Xcode:

> -com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1

Could anyone please advise me, how to call the `newBackgroundContext()` on the proper thread?

**UPDATE:**

I have tried to workaround my problem as in below code, but the error is the same:

```
URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
    .tryMap(handleOutput)
    .decode(type: TopResponse.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
    .sink { completion in
        print(completion)
    } receiveValue: { returnedTops in
        let backgroundContext = PersistenceController.shared.container.newBackgroundContext()

        for top in returnedTops.data {
            // the next line fails with EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION
            let topEntity = TopEntity(context: backgroundContext)
            topEntity.uid = Int32(top.id)
            topEntity.elo = Int32(top.elo)
            topEntity.given = top.given
            topEntity.avg_score = top.avg_score ?? 0.0
        }

        do {
            try backgroundContext.save()
        } catch {
            let nsError = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
        }
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I was assuming that when `newBackgroundContext()` is called, it takes the current thread and then you can use that context from the same thread...

This seems not to be the case and I have to call `perform`, `performAndWait` or `performBackgroundTask` (I have updated [my code at Github](https://github.com/afarber/ios-questions/blob/master/Tops1/Tops1/Managers/DownloadManager.swift) to do just that).

Still I wonder, if the thread of `newBackgroundContext` can be the same as of the `URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher`...

Comment: you should look into [batch insert](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsbatchinsertrequest) there are plenty of tutorials on it.

Comment: Yes +1 but my question is about threads and not about the fastest way to insert objects. And also `automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true` would not work with batch insert and I would like to keep my code simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you have figured most of this out yourself.

> This seems not to be the case and I have to call perform, `performAndWait` or `performBackgroundTask` (I have updated my code at Github to do just that).

What's still not solved is here -

> Still I wonder, if the thread of `newBackgroundContext` can be the same as of the `URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher...`

---

The `URLSession` API allows you to provide a custom response queue like following.

```
URLSession.shared
    .dataTaskPublisher(for: URL(string: "https://google.com")!)
    .receive(on: DispatchQueue(label: "API.responseQueue", qos: .utility)) // <--- HERE
    .sink(receiveCompletion: {_ in }, receiveValue: { (output) in
          print(output)
     })
```

OR traditionally like this -

```
let queue = OperationQueue()
queue.underlyingQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "API.responseQueue", qos: .utility)
let session = URLSession(configuration: .default, delegate: self, delegateQueue: queue)
```

So ideally, we should pass in the `NSManagedObjectContext`'s `DispatchQueue` as the reponse queue for `URLSession`.

---

The issue is with `NSManagedObjectContext` API that -

1. neither allows you to supply a custom `DispatchQueue` instance from outside.
2. nor exposes a read-only property for it's internally managed `DispatchQueue` instance.

We can't access underlying `DispatchQueue` for `NSManagedObjectContext` instance. The ONLY EXCEPTION to this rule is `.viewContext` that uses `DispatchQueue.main`. Of course we don't want to handle network response decoding and thousands of records being created/persisted on/from main thread.